# Need clarification on below if else statement

Tags: java

```
  public int compare(final Item i1, final Item i2) {
        final Float itemCode1 = i1.getItemCode();
        final Float itemCode2 = i2.getItemCode();

        return itemCode1 == null ? -1 :
               itemCode2 == null ? 1 :
               i1.getItemCode().compareTo(itemCode2);}
```

This is a code snippet on which i need clarification.Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What exactly do you need clarification about? And there's no if/else statement there... just two conditional operators.

Comment: the title of this question don't fit its content, its a compare and no if/else

Answer (score 1):

It compares two `Item` objects.

If the first `Item`'s code is null, it returns -1, which means the first `Item` would be ordered before the second `Item`.

Otherwise, if the second `Item`'s code is null, it returns 1, which means the second `Item` would be ordered before the first `Item`.

Otherwise the two item codes would be compared (comparison of two floating point numbers), and the result of that comparison would determine the order.

Answer (score 0):

It's the beautiful double ternair that bothers you ?

It means the same as :

```
If(itemCode1 == null)
    return -1;
else if (itemCode2 == null)
    return 1;
else
    return i1.getItemCode().compareTo(itemCode2);
```

AS you can see using multi ternaires is not very readable so avoid this pratice ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to the following code:

```
public int compare(final Item i1, final Item i2) {
    final Float itemCode1 = i1.getItemCode();
    final Float itemCode2 = i2.getItemCode();

    if (itemCode1 == null) {
        return -1;
    } else if (itemCode2 == null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        // I changed from i1.getItemCode() to itemCode1
        return itemCode1.compareTo(itemCode2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(itemCode1 == null) 
{
 //-1
}
else{
   if( itemCode2 ==null){
     {//1}
   else{
i1.getItemCode().compareTo(itemCode2)
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and preferably explain your solution.